# Trouble setting up WebDAV

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, webdav

0  vote down  star

Rather than using FTP to access my hosting provider, which I read is unsecure, I'm trying to set up WebDAV (which I've never done before). I don't see WebDAV in the Actions pane of IIS Manager. So I found a link at http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDAV to install it. I'm running Windows 7, so when the Web Platform Installer gave a message that my operating system is not supported, I tried the x64 link from that site. Then I get the message "IIS Version 7.0 is required to use WebDav 7.5 for IIS". That would suggest I didn't install IIS7, which I'm pretty positive I did. In IIS Manager the Help | About says Version 6.1 (Build 7600) at the top (6.1 makes me think IIS6?) but then at the bottom it says "Internet Information Services (Version 7.5.7600.16385), which seems to suggest IIS7, right?  And in fact, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp says Version 7.5.  Any ideas on how I can get going with WebDAV? Thanks!
(ps - I thought this posted earlier, but I don't see it, so hopefully this isn't a dupe.)

Comment: WebDAV is only more secure if it's done over https://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What operating system are you using?  Windows Server 2003 has IIS6, 2008 has IIS7 and 2008 R2 has 7.5.

If you have IIS7 then FTPS (FTP over SSL) is available which is a good secure option.  It's a matter of preference if you go with WebDAV or FTPS.

Comment: WebDAV is probably a bit wider in implementation, and far more likely to sneak across firewalls.

Comment: Than FTPS, yes.  FTP is more common than WebDAV, but FTPS is less common.  FTPS does have some firewall considerations and requires multiple ports open.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 on my machine and Windows 2008 on the server.  The server is DiscountASP.Net.  I found <a href="http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=2715&highlight=webdav">this link</a> in which DASP states: 
- webdav is a no-no on windows. it's a source of MANY security holes.
- https is the only secure way to upload to discountasp.net. 
- Enable SSL and use FrontPage extension to upload via HTTPS.

Note: I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: WebDAV with IIS6 was an issue, I agree, but that's changed with IIS7 which had fixed the issues and is now an excellent secure solution.  That said, my personal preference, mostly because I know it better, is FTPS.

Stay away from FrontPage extensions at all costs.  

To setup FTPS, make sure that the FTP extensions are enabled.  If you're using pre-R2 then it's a separate download: http://www.iis.net/extensions/FTP

Then on the site, add a binding for FTP.  Once you do that an refresh the view for your site, you'll have a bunch of FTP icons that are reasonably straight forward to use.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using DiscountASP.Net and have logged a question in with them on whether they support FTPS (since I thought I saw a post saying they don't, though it may have been outdated.)

Comment: Indeed, they do support it:
"We support FTP over SSL on our IIS 7.0 platform.

See http://support.discountasp.net/KB/c77/ftp.aspx "

Comment: Excellent. That sounds like your best bet then.